# Connectedness condition by basis\sub-basis

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know that some basic topological properties like compactness, $T_0$ and $T_1$ are among the properties which can be tested by a basis of the topology. I was wondering whether there is such a condition for connectedness of certain topological spaces?

For example, clearly if $\mathcal{B}$ is a sub-basis and $E,E^c\in \mathcal{B}$, then the space is not connected. It seems likely that we should be able obtain some sort condition and thought that perhaps someone here would know of such a condition.